# Convert J1939 message to raw CAN

Tags: c++, embedded, can-bus, j1939

I'm receiving J1939 CAN messages trough a class that uses IsoAgLib as framework. On the receiver side I have these J1939 messages that need to get transmitted to the CAN network by using Qt's "QCanBusDevice" and "QCBusFrame".

My question is: how can I convert a message in J1939 protocol to a raw can message and vice-versa?

Comment: J1939 is just a higher layer, which is used as payload by a CAN frame. Therefore, a J1939 message _is_ a CAN frame. As for how to parse this using your specific library, I have no idea. Basically you should have a 29 bit identifier, a DLC (data size), up to 8 bytes of data, and that's pretty much it. (I don't remember if J1939 allows RTR, if so you have to consider that as well)

Comment: Yeah.. basically I need to know if having pgn, source address, data, etc how to pack all that data in order to it send to the network.

Comment: Read any J1939 explanation. For example, http://www.simmasoftware.com/j1939-presentation.pdf page 21 interprets message id as j1939 fields.

Answer (score 0):

J1939 is only a protocol layer, so you first need to create the CAN ID based on the priority, PGN and source address of the J1939 message, The CAN ID is 29bit length use the following structure as example:

-priority       0x18

-PGN            0xFECA

-Source address 0x00

The structure above it is an example of one of the J1939 messages ID, the raw ID will be the same 0x18FECA00. J1939 only dictates how to interpret the raw information.

Now to assemble the payload will depends on the parameter length in bits, the start bit and the offset.

-Identify the data length
-assemble all the bytes according to the J1939 signal information
You can find this on the SAE J1939-71 and SAE J1939-73 documents.